# flowplayer-3.2.18 playing Video file with black screen

Tags: flowplayer

I'm using flowplayer-3.2.18 plugin in a html file to play video files uploaded in my Media server.  I'm trying to play a .FLV file in Flowplayer, file is loaded and played but with a black screen! Can anybody help to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue too and didn't find good solution.

But this is deffenetelly related to the video codecs. I changed my video codec for my video file and it works now.

Also you can try to check this video file using [Wowza player](http://www.wowza.com/resources/3.5.0/examples/LiveVideoStreaming/FlashRTMPPlayer/player.html) and if it doesn't work too you can be sure that is something wrong with video file